# Euler's Formula For Different Bases

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I was messing around with Euler's formula by changing up the values $e$ and $\pi$, and found the following trend:

$$a^{i\frac{\Large \pi}{\Large \log(a)}} = -1$$

It seems to work for all positive real numbers. Is this true? I haven't learned about the identity in school so I apologize if this is trivial or common sense. Thanks!

Comment: The case $a=1$ is problematic.

Comment: $ln(a)$ should be the right syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, $a^z=e^{z\log a}$. So, for any $\lambda$, 
$$
a^{i\lambda}=e^{\lambda\log a}. 
$$
To get $-1$, we need $\lambda\log a=i(2k+1)\pi$ for $k\in \mathbb N$. In particular, for $k=0$, we get $\lambda=i\pi/\log a$. So, as you say,
$$
a^{\dfrac{i\pi}{\log a}}=-1.
$$

Comment: If $a=1$, we should probably avoid the principal branch.

Comment: Good point. Kind of overkill, though :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For $a>0$ and $a\ne 1$ we have $a^{1/\log a}=e$